# can't connect to mysql using nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, cmd, server

i am new to nodejs ,while creating a connection to the database i got this errors

> C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
>           throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user
>   'Root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>       at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
>       at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:103:18)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
>       at Parser.write (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
>       at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
>       at Connection.connect (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\devashis khandelwal\node files\demo_db_connection.js:9:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'Root',
  password : 'my_pass',
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You are connecting with user `Root`, I believe it is `root`. Your error is clearly a credentials error.

Answer (score 2):

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:  it's occurred because of permission.

As far as I understand your above code you need to change Root to root

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'my_pass',
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where I was able to login using the CLI with same creds, but didn't work with `mysql2` in nodejs (`mysql-server 8.0`). Solved it by using `%` in place of `localhost`:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

instead of

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```